# More efficent way for string replace to mask a json file (java)

Tags: java, regex, masking

I have some code to mask the values in a json file. 
But i have the feeling that there should be a more efficent way to do this.

This is my current code:

```
private static final String STRING_REPLACEMENT = "$1 \"String\" $4";
private static final String FLOAT_REPLACEMENT = "$1 \"float\" $4";
private static final String INT_REPLACEMENT = "$1 \"Integer\" $4";
private static final String BOOL_REPLACEMENT = "$1 \"Boolean\" $4";
```

And the actual masking code:

```
out = out.replaceAll("(\"\\w+\"\\s?:)\\s?\"((\\\\\"|[^\"])*\")", "$1 \"String\"");
out = out.replaceAll("(\"\\w+\"\\s?:)\\s?(\\d+\\.\\d+)", "$1 \"float\"");
out = out.replaceAll("(\"\\w+\"\\s?:)\\s?(\\d+)", "$1 \"Integer\"");
out = out.replaceAll("(\"\\w+\"\\s?:)\\s?(true|false)", "$1 \"Boolean\"");

out = out.replaceAll("(\\[\\s?)\"((\\\\\"|[^\"])*\")(\\s?,)", STRING_REPLACEMENT);
out = out.replaceAll("(,\\s?)\"((\\\\\"|[^\"])*\")(\\s?,)", STRING_REPLACEMENT);
out = out.replaceAll("(,\\s?)\"((\\\\\"|[^\"])*\")(\\s?\\])", STRING_REPLACEMENT);

out = out.replaceAll("(\\[\\s?)((\\d)+\\.\\d+)(\\s?,)", FLOAT_REPLACEMENT);
out = out.replaceAll("(,\\s?)((\\d)+\\.\\d+)(\\s?,)", FLOAT_REPLACEMENT);
out = out.replaceAll("(,\\s?)((\\d)+\\.\\d+)(\\s?\\])", FLOAT_REPLACEMENT);

out = out.replaceAll("(\\[\\s?)((\\d)+)(\\s?,)", INT_REPLACEMENT);
out = out.replaceAll("(,\\s?)((\\d)+)(\\s?,)", INT_REPLACEMENT);
out = out.replaceAll("(,\\s?)((\\d)+)(\\s?\\])", INT_REPLACEMENT);

out = out.replaceAll("(\\[\\s?)((true|false))(\\s?,)", BOOL_REPLACEMENT);
out = out.replaceAll("(,\\s?)((true|false))(\\s?,)", BOOL_REPLACEMENT);
out = out.replaceAll("(,\\s?)((true|false))(\\s?\\])", BOOL_REPLACEMENT);
```

does someone have any suggestions how to improve this. I know that i can group the regex a bit but I am afraid that that will influence the readability to mutch. And i noticed that if I combine the 3 regex lines into one with more ? in it that it not always finds it in the correct way so the masking fails then.

Comment: I would avoid performing any type of replacements in a structured language such as JSON by treating it a `String` and using regular expressions to start with. It's hard to tell the efficiency here (as it will also depend on the size of the payload and occurrences, etc.) but for readability/maintainability you may want to use a JSON parser/writer instead and re-create the object.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a HashMap with your regex/replacement and iterate over to apply your replaceAll

for example

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Test {

    private static final String STRING_REPLACEMENT = "$1 \"String\" $4";
    private static final String FLOAT_REPLACEMENT = "$1 \"float\" $4";
    private static final String INT_REPLACEMENT = "$1 \"Integer\" $4";
    private static final String BOOL_REPLACEMENT = "$1 \"Boolean\" $4";
    private static final Map<String,String> patterns;
    static {
        patterns = new HashMap<>();
        patterns.put("(\"\\w+\"\\s?:)\\s?\"((\\\\\"|[^\"])*\")", "$1 \"String\"");
        patterns.put("(\"\\w+\"\\s?:)\\s?(\\d+\\.\\d+)", "$1 \"float\"");
        patterns.put("(\"\\w+\"\\s?:)\\s?(\\d+)", "$1 \"Integer\"");
        patterns.put("(\"\\w+\"\\s?:)\\s?(true|false)", "$1 \"Boolean\"");
        patterns.put("(\\[\\s?)\"((\\\\\"|[^\"])*\")(\\s?,)", STRING_REPLACEMENT);
        patterns.put("(,\\s?)\"((\\\\\"|[^\"])*\")(\\s?,)", STRING_REPLACEMENT);
        patterns.put("(,\\s?)\"((\\\\\"|[^\"])*\")(\\s?\\])", STRING_REPLACEMENT);
        patterns.put("(\\[\\s?)((\\d)+\\.\\d+)(\\s?,)", FLOAT_REPLACEMENT);
        patterns.put("(,\\s?)((\\d)+\\.\\d+)(\\s?,)", FLOAT_REPLACEMENT);
        patterns.put("(,\\s?)((\\d)+\\.\\d+)(\\s?\\])", FLOAT_REPLACEMENT);
        patterns.put("(\\[\\s?)((\\d)+)(\\s?,)", INT_REPLACEMENT);
        patterns.put("(,\\s?)((\\d)+)(\\s?,)", INT_REPLACEMENT);
        patterns.put("(,\\s?)((\\d)+)(\\s?\\])", INT_REPLACEMENT);
        patterns.put("(\\[\\s?)((true|false))(\\s?,)", BOOL_REPLACEMENT);
        patterns.put("(,\\s?)((true|false))(\\s?,)", BOOL_REPLACEMENT);
        patterns.put("(,\\s?)((true|false))(\\s?\\])", BOOL_REPLACEMENT);
    }
    public void test() {
        String out="your string";
        for(Map.Entry<String, String> pattern :patterns.entrySet()){
            out = out.replaceAll(pattern.getKey(), pattern.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

**But, it will be better to unserialize, update values and re serialize your json with an api**

Comment: But that woudn't realy make it more efficient. I guess it will eventually even be more inefficient and it will have more code than the current implementation.

Comment: you're right it s not more efficient. but i think is  a little bit more clean